# Connecting 1/2 copper to 1/8 pex?

Tags: plumbing, pex, ice-maker

Water line to fridge had a saddle valve, saddle valve started leaking so took it out and repaired pipe. Now trying to figure out how to reconnect fridge line. I have 1/2 inch copper under the sink and the pex line at the fridge says 1/8 on it. I can't find any adapters that go from 1/2 to 1/8,or even 1/4 to 1/8. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: That is why they make saddle valves. You could pit a T in line and get several adapters to make it down to 1/8. Are you sure of the size most of the ones I have installed are 1/4"

Comment: @EdBeal saddle valves are no good. They usually just end up leaking. In many areas, licensed plumbers are not even allowed to install them.

Comment: Ed beal, the pex coming out of the fridge has 1/8" printed on it. Maybe the actual connection at the fridge is 1/4, but the line currently connected is 1/8.

Comment: What is the make and model of the fridge? What does the shutoff valve for the sink look like (what size is the outlet)?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to tee off the 1/2" copper line, then you can start with something like this.

[image]

Once you get down to 1/4" copper tube, you can reduce further to 1/8" tube as follows.

[image]

---

If you want to tee off after the sink shutoff valve, we'll need to know what size the outlet is on the valve.

Answer (score 1):

Dont use plastic water lines going to fridge  I see them leak all the time. Use 1/4 flexible copper with compression fittings or 1/4 flexible braided stainless steel supply line(like going to your faucet) I have seen them up to 20' long.

The easiest ways is to install a compression nut T. You unscrew your supply line from your sink to the shut off valve and screw in the compression nut T. Your water line from sink and icemaker will both screw into this.
Just take a trip your local hardware store and ask for help this is a very common issue. 
[image]

Comment: OP states that the line to the fridge is 1/8", not 1/4".

Comment: Refridgetors  uses 1/4 compression for water maker.

Comment: I agree that that's the common convention, however, the OP specifically said that it's 1/8".

Comment: Pex tub says 1/8 on it  but that is inside diameter. The line comes with a 1/4 compression fitting on ends just like a stainless steel braided line. Your not suppose to cut the line if he did he needs new line.

Comment: A pex water line is  strong and safe to use. I was thinking of cheap plastic lines.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting a 1/2 to 1/4 SharkBite adapter, then a 1/4 to 1/4 stainless steel line to connect to the adapter on the pex.  The pex does say 1/8 on it, but one of the posters correctly pointed out that's an inside diameter. Thanks all!